# Huge ext4 filesystem mount slow

Tags: mount, filesystem, ext4

Hoping you can help:

I've got an ubuntu 16.04 NFS server and over time, I've had to repeatedly grow an ext4 filesystem, which at this point is 85TB. Now it takes about 60 seconds to mount this filesystem, and because the nfs service depends on local filesystems being mounted, the nfs-mountd.service process fails on boot, and throws me into a recovery shell. If I comment out the huge filesystem in the fstab, the system boots fine.

Is there anything I can do (short of copying 85TB to a separate 85TB xfs filesystem which I don't have) that will allow the filesystem to mount in a reasonable amount of time?

I'm mounting it w/ default options.

EDIT:

Apparently the answer to my question is "no". So I created a separate 85TB XFS filesystem, kicked everyone off the server and it's NFS clients, moved the data to the XFS filesystem, then mounted the XFS fs at the original mount point. Several hours later users were back at work, and months later, the filesystem continues to grow in size.

From now on, all new filesystems are XFS our shop (w/ rare exceptions like /boot/efi).